# HapiJS + hapi-mongo-models server stuck on 504 (http error)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, hapi.js

I have my NodeJS server in a weird mode that returns 504 on every API call.
Here is my stuck:

1. Node JS using HapiJS (hapi@11.1.4, hapi-mongo-models@3.0.0).
2. Node is served by PM2 (single instance no clustering).
3. Request to the Node server are being served through NGINX proxy.

After using this server the past 6 months, the last few days, the server, after a certain period of time (it can be 5 minutes or 24 hours), is entering this mode where **every API call** that is using the **hapi-mongo-models** to connect to MongoDB returns 504 (after about a minute of waiting).

Here is what I've tried:

1. I've checked the NGINX status - other requests such as static pages are working fine. I've also tested resources that doesn't require the usage of MongoDB at all and they work fine as well. So no NGINX problem.
2. I've tried looking at the V8 stack size using (https://github.com/felixge/node-stack-trace) but no luck there either, it's standing constantly on about ~50 items, where request are being flushed normally.
3. I've created a resource that is able to eval stuff on runtime, so I can debug internally my server. This has resulted my to figure that the MongoDB itself works just fine. Since if I directly use the mongodb module:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'); 
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient; 
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/xxxxxxxxxxx'; 
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) { 
    if (err) { 
        reply(err) 
    } else { 
        var Users = db.collection('users'); 
        Users.find({userId: '119507586'}).toArray().then(function (err, users) {
            reply(err);
            db.close()
        });
    } 
});
```

It works perfectly fine (if this method is being requested it returns a valid value while other API calls are returning 504 -- the ones that uses the hapi-mongo-models).

4. I've looked at both the NGINX requests&errors logs and the application log, looking for suspicious requests that might cause some internal loop or crash, but couldn't find anything (I've tried reproducing the error calling the exact same set of requests the were right before the server turned into its 504 mode).

At this point I think I've narrowed it down into the following options:

1. Some content, on some request, causing the `BaseModel` (one of its accessors such as `user`) --> `require('hapi-mongo-models').BaseModel` to some internal error, hence every model that extends `BaseModel` is having a problem.
2. Bug?

And so I need help:)
Any thoughts, ideas and help is more than welcome!
THX!